# Find size of double * array C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, double

If I have declared a `double *positions[2]` array, is there a way of finding the actual size of the `double *positions[2]` array?

Is there like a `sizeof` function to find the size?

I have tried an example, and it does not return the size as `4`

http://ideone.com/vp3tJz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: You don't need any code for this. The length of the array is `2`. That's known at compile time.

Comment: No I meant the number of elements stored inside the pointer array

Comment: Why didn't you ask that then? The answer is that you cannot find how many elements are in a dynamically allocated array if all you have is a pointer to the array. My question to you is why you feel compelled to call `new[]` at all. You can avoid all these problems by using standard containers.

Comment: Actually looking at your code, I wonder what you expect `coord[2]` and `coord[3]` to mean. You declared `coord` like this `double *cord[2]`. Do you understand what the `2` means in that statement. In other words, if you want to use 4 elements, why did you reserve 2?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `sizeof`?
Expression

```
sizeof( positions )
```

will return the size of the array in bytes that is equal do `2 * sizeof( double * )`
Or you can use standard class `std::extent` to determine the num ber of elements in an array. For example

```
std::cout << std::extent<decltype( positions )>::value << std::endl;
```

As for your edited post then the declaration of the array does not correspond to the values you showed. The array is defined as having pointers as its elements  not double values.

If you want to define an array that will be initialized with values

```
0.1, 2.5
10.0, 56.7
12.4, 20.1
69.9, 69.9
72.1, 45.0
```

then you should write

```
double positions[5][2] =
{
    { 0.1, 2.5 },
    { 10.0, 56.7 },
    { 12.4, 20.1 },
    { 69.9, 69.9 },
    { 72.1, 45.0 }
};
```

In this case `sizeof( positions )` will be equal to `5 * 2 * sizeof( double )`

Or

```
sizeof( position ) / sizeof( *positions )
```

will be equal to 5 and

```
sizeof( *position ) / sizeof( **positions )
```

will be equal to 2

Comment: So if the `double` array had `5` sets of `x,y` co-ordinates, `sizeof` will return `5`?

Comment: @Stu User What is "sets of x,y coordinates"?!

Comment: I have edited the question, please refer to it. Like it has 5 rows of x,y co-ordinates, so will `size-of` return 5?

Comment: @Stu User The sizeof operator returns the size of an array in bytes. It does not calculates  If for example an array has 5 elements of type double then the operator will return 5 * sizeof( double ). If you need to know the number of elements in the array you should use expression sizeof( array ) / sizeof( double ) or class std:;extent as I showed.

Comment: Thanks, so I will need to do `sizeof(positions)/sizeof(double)` to get number of elements?

Comment: @Stu User See my updated post.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it doesn't return the number of elements, I did my code on IDEone - http://ideone.com/vp3tJz

Comment: @Stu User  What does not work?

Comment: There are `4` elements and it only returns `2`.

Comment: @Stu User I do not see what has 4 elements. Please read my post. There is all described.

Comment: The answer describes sizeof() for arrays like double[x][y], but not for arrays of pointers. Eg. sizeof(double* [2]) is 2*sizeof(double*), because it is unknown where the pointers are pointing just, that it is an array with two double pointers.